# How can i delete or modify a user defined field in Oracle Identity Manager?

Tags: oim

I have to delete or modify a user defined field in Oracle Identity Manager due to a mistake i made.Can that be achieved by making a new sandbox?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I should probably mention that the mistake was made in Oracle Identity System Administration webconsole.

Comment: what exactly is the mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though this thread is posted earlier. I have faced same kind of problem.

We can delete or modify a User Defined Field(UDF) before we publish it.
We can export the sandbox and make change or delete the field (in files after extracting the sandbox).

If you have already published the sandbox you can revert back the sandboxes but for that you need to have all the exported sandboxes which are already published. Then you can make your change manually in files of sandbox and republish those.

This idea worked for me.

Comment: If we try to delete the UDF by reverting the published sandbox it will be removed from the UI but what about the OIM DB, that will be still present there??